# Alternative to nesting for loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I've read that one of the key beliefs of Python is that flat > nested. However, if I have several variables counting up, what is the alternative to multiple for loops?
My code is for counting grid sums and goes as follows:

```
def horizontal():
    for x in range(20):
        for y in range(17):
            temp = grid[x][y: y + 4]
            sum = 0
            for n in temp:
                sum += int(n)
            print sum # EDIT: the return instead of print was a mistype
```

This seems to me like it is too heavily nested. Firstly, what is considered to many nested loops in Python ( I have certainly seen 2 nested loops before). Secondly, if this is too heavily nested, what is an alternative way to write this code?

Comment: You're looking for [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here.

Comment: Are you sure your return statement is inside 2 for loops?

Comment: 0xc0de, that was mistype (I meant print), thank you for pointing it out

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Are you sure your return statement is inside 2 for loops?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

def horizontal():
    for x, y in product(range(20), range(17)):
        print 1 + sum(int(n) for n in grid[x][y: y + 4])
```

You should be using the `sum` function. Of course you can't if you shadow it with a variable, so I changed it to `my_sum`

Comment: I'd use `xrange` instead of `range`. I'd also agree that the `return` inside the loop is a bug.

Comment: @Balthamos, for small ranges, `range` is faster, and there is no `xrange` in Python3. OP doesn't mention which version they are using

Comment: You can just stick the return at the sum calculation line. As you correctly noted, return will stop execution and the next statement after the call will be executed. Since there is no need for the `my_sum` variable (it can't be used after the return call), there is no need to declare it. In short, `return 1 + sum(int(n) for n in grid[x][y: y + 4])`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, OP clarified that it should just be a `print` there

Comment: Ah, okay. Not recommended to print stuff in methods as the final result. This causes the method to return `None` and surprises if you do `print horizontal()`

Comment: This section of code is not finished yet. The print is just checking that it is doing all sums, and later I will have it only return the highest

Comment: @davenz, The `max` function can help you with that. You just need to shift things around a little

Answer (score 1):

```
grid = [range(20) for i in range(20)]
sum(sum( 1 + sum(grid[x][y: y + 4]) for y in range(17)) for x in range(20))
```

The above outputs 13260, for the particular grid created in the first line of code.  It uses `sum()` three times.  The innermost sum adds up the numbers in `grid[x][y: y + 4]`, plus the slightly strange initial value `sum = 1` shown in the code in the question.  The middle sum adds up those values for the 17 possible y values.  The outer sum adds up the middle values over possible x values.

If elements of grid are strings instead of numbers, replace
`sum(grid[x][y: y + 4])`
with
`sum(int(n) for n in grid[x][y: y + 4]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to optimize performance significantly

This is another example:

```
locations = {}
for i in range(len(airports)):
    locations[airports["abb"][i][1:-1]] = (airports["height"][i], airports["width"][i])

for i in range(len(uniqueData)):
    h, w = locations[uniqueData["dept_apt"][i]]
    uniqueData["dept_apt_height"][i] = h
    uniqueData["dept_apt_width"][i] = w
```