# Python Nested Loop Alternative

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have two large lists containing text.
X = [30,000 entries] and
Y = [400 entries]

I want to find out the text which are similar in both the list using cosine similarity.
Below is the code which I am trying to execute using nested for loops

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
found_words = []
for x in X:
    for y in Y:
       vector1 = vectorizer(x.lower())
       vector2 = vectorizer(y.lower())
       sim = cosine_similarity(vector1, vector2)
       if sim > 0.9:
           found_words.append(x.capitalize())
```

The above code works fine but takes a lot of time to execute. Is there any other way which can be efficient in time as well as space complexity. Thank you

Comment: Similar answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908518/alternative-to-nesting-for-loops-in-python

Comment: I did look at that but since my lists are huge, it takes equal amount of time to execute compared to nested for loops

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850508/python-nested-list-comprehension-with-if-else

Comment: Have you given a look at the multiprocessing module?

Comment: @PujariRajagonda I checked even using List comprehension. I am not sure if it's outright efficient since I am not just comparing the text but calculating the cosine similarity here

Comment: @SandeepGusain Do you think spawning multiple processes could help?

Comment: You can split the **X** array into multiple chunks which can then be processed simultaneously

Comment: this solution might help you reach your goal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists

Comment: What happens when you move: `vector1 = vectorizer(x.lower())` to just before `for y in Y:`?

Comment: @quamrana That's a very good point but I didn't see substantial decrease in execution time

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you will need `multiprocessing`. Anyway, you should just perform the `s.lower()` once for each string, so you might want, eg, `Y = [y.lower() for y in Y]` before the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cosine, you can calculate the dot-product of normalised vectors. Then, vectorisation can be done before this operation.

Here is my attempt to replicate the test with random vectors:

```
import numpy as np 

# assume vector dimension is 100:
a = np.random.random([30000, 100]) # X vectors
b = np.random.random([400, 100]) # Y vectors

a = np.array([[_v/np.linalg.norm(_v)] for _v in a]) # shape (30000, d, 1)
b = np.array([[_v/np.linalg.norm(_v)] for _v in b]) # shape (400, d, 1)

sims = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=([1,2], [1,2]))

print(np.where(sims > 0.87)[0]) # index of matched item in X
```

I reduced the threshold to `0.87` to be able to show some results in my random vectors.

Replace the random `a` and `b` with the vectorisation code:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
a = [vectorizer(s.lower()) for s in X]
b = [vectorizer(s.lower()) for s in Y]
```

Also, in the end, you need to use the `X` indices to get back to the actual source.

```
x_indices, _ = np.where(sims > 0.9)
x_indices = set(list(x_indices)) # avoid possible duplicate matches
found_words = [X[i] for i in x_indices]
```

If you have access to an Nvidia GPU with CUDA support, you can use that for faster/parallelized tensor operations. You can use `torch` to access the device:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
a = [vectorizer(s.lower()) for s in X]
b = [vectorizer(s.lower()) for s in Y]

# normalize the vectors and also convert them to tensor types
a = torch.tensor([[_v/np.linalg.norm(_v)] for _v in a], device='cuda') # shape (30000, d, 1)
b = torch.tensor([[_v/np.linalg.norm(_v)] for _v in b], device='cuda') # shape (400, d, 1)

sims = torch.tensordot(a, b, dims=([1, 2], [1, 2])).cpu().numpy()
# shape (30000, 400)

x_indices, _ = np.where(sims > 0.9)
x_indices = set(list(x_indices)) # avoid possible duplicate matches
found_words = [X[i] for i in x_indices]
```